# Google static API large zoomed map

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

**Hi,**

For a project i'm working on I **need** a **lot of maps** from **different places** around the world **zoomed to building level**. I tried to use **Google static map API** and **python** to achieve that. I planned to divide the area I need and take multiple pictures in a for loop. But i don't know **how to take the exact zone next to the previous one.**

*Here is my code:*

```
import requests

apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
#center peut être égal soit au nom d'une ville, d'un pays, continent ou 
{latitude,longitude}
center = "Binche"
zoom = 13

completeUrl = url + "center=" + center + "&zoom=" + str(zoom) + "&size=640x640&key=" + 
apiKey + "&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off"

r = requests.get(completeUrl)

with open(center + " Zoom " + str(zoom) + ".png", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(r.content)
```

*And here is my result:*

[image]

Everything is good... Except i **need** a **way bigger area**. And to have an area this big I had to put the zoom value to 13 (i would like 20).

**So, How could i have multiple pictures (or a single one) of a zone (~100Km). And another question would it cost a lot with this API ? If you think it's not possible and you have another idea feel free to write it :).**

*Thanks for your time !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you want to know is these:

*1. How to load a static map of a large area*

*2. How much would it cost*

**Answer #1**

You should check out this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#Zoomlevels) to learn more about zoom levels.

Larger zoom levels does not mean a bigger area, in fact, it's the other way around.

> *Maps on Google Maps have an integer 'zoom level' which defines the resolution of the current view. Zoom levels between 0 (the lowest zoom level, in which the entire world can be seen on one map) and 21+ (down to streets and individual buildings) are possible within the default roadmap view....*

> *The following list shows the approximate level of detail you can expect to see at each zoom level:
>
> 1: World
>
> 5: Landmass/continent
>
> 10: City
>
> 15: Streets
>
> 20: Buildings*

So what you should do is to change your `zoom` value lower.

**Answer #2**

You should check out this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing#new-payg)

> *The Maps Static API uses a pay-as-you-go pricing model. The Google Maps Platform APIs and SDKs are billed by SKU. Usage is tracked for each SKU, and any API or SDK may have more than one product SKU. Cost is calculated by SKU usage × Price per each use.*

The "per each use" here means *per map **LOAD***. This means that regardless of the zoom levels that you use, you will only be billed per LOAD of the Static Maps API. That means if you load multiple static maps, you will be billed per map that you loaded. And it costs around 0.002 USD per LOAD if your load amount per month does not exceed 100,000. You can check the pricing table on the link I provided for more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! And sorry for my english it's not on point...  The answer 2 is what I need, thanks. And for the 1, I need a map zoomed to building level (17), but of a large area. For Example: let's say I want a to see on a map every buildings of France. I planned to take every 256x256 tile of France put them in photoshop and create a large map. But how can I take all these tile. Thanks for your time.

Comment: And thanks for the edit ! I forgot to review my code since it was not a really important part of my post :(.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. You can mark my answer as accepted if my answer satisfies you. It would be much appreciated

Comment: @Zartox29 Regarding question #1, do you mean that you want to download that the google maps API generated and use it on Photoshop?

Comment: Yeah, that's it ! To form a big map with streets and buildings apparent.

Comment: And right now it work, but i need to get a way bigger area.

Comment: Oh, before you proceed with your project, please make sure that you're not violating their Terms of Service. For what I know, It is against their ToS to download generated maps and use it for other content.

Please see [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services).

Comment: Yes, you are right... I'm back to my starting point. And i still don't know what to use to achieve this... But anyway thanks for your help ! I'll find another way to make my map :/.